# js on click делает div видимым, но не может закрыть его wp loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Опять wp loop...

Есть код

```html
<?php /*Start the loop*/ ?>
 <?php $specialistquery = new WP_Query('category_name=our-specialists'); ?>
 <?php while ( $specialistquery->have_posts()) : $specialistquery->the_post()?>
  <div class="full clear">
   <img class="close-full" src="" alt="Закрыть">
   <div class="full-info clear">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <p class="name visible"><?php the_title() ?></p>
    <div class="post-content">
     <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' ); ?>
    </div>
    <p class="specialization visible"></p>
    <p class="education visible"></p> 
    <p class="experience visible">Стаж более лет</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.close-full').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.post-content').css({'display':'none'});
  });
  
  $('.full').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.post-content').css({'display':'inline'});
  });
</script>
```

Суть в том, что когда кликаешь по div он раскрывается и появляется полная инфа с кнопкой закрыть. Когда кликаешь закрыть, div должен свернуться в первоначальное состояние.

div появляется но close-full не срабатывает. Вообще ничего не происходит.

Я так подозреваю, что все дело в родителях и т.д. Только не могу понять к чему тогда привязаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.close-full').click(function(){
 $(this).next('div').find('.post-content').css({'display':'none'});
 });
$('.full').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.post-content').css({'display':'inline'});
  $(this).find('.specialization').css({'display':'none'});
  $(this).find('.education').css({'display':'none'});
  $(this).find('.experience').css({'display':'none'});
  $(this).find('.full-info').css({'cursor':'auto','background-color':'#f1f5f5','box-shadow':'7px 5px 0 rgba(228,231,231,1)'});
  $(this).find('.close-full').css({'display':'block'});
  $(this).find('.attachment-post-thumbnail').css({'margin':'0 30px 25px 0','width':'300px','height':'300px'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="specialist-content">
       <img class="close-full" src="" alt="Закрыть">
    <div class="full clear">
    <div class="full-info clear">
            the_post_thumbnail()
           <p class="name visible">php the_title()</p>
           <div class="post-content">
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' )
           </div>
           <p class="specialization visible"></p>
           <p class="education visible"></p> 
           <p class="experience visible">Стаж более лет</p>
   </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Я немного ошибся, задавая свой вопрос. .close-full находится внутри .full. Как я понял, то мне надо при помощи селектора добраться до .full Но ничего не выходит. По идее должен подойти prev()  но нет

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите так https://jsfiddle.net/2f89fya7/ ?